# Basso profilo Vs profilo basso

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Normalmente si usa il termine **basso profilo** per indicare *fatti, situazioni, persone di scarsa rappresentatività* (cit. [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/profilo/)).

Ma mi è capitato di usare in alcuni casi **profilo basso**, ad esempio nella frase:

```
Ragazzi, non esaltiamoci, manteniamo un profilo basso.
```

Vorrei sapere, se la frase è corretta (con l'uso di `profilo basso`) e se il significato non cambia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Penso che non dipenda dal fatto di mettere prima il sostantivo  o l'aggettivo, ma dal contesto:

- quando arriva un nuovo capo è consigliabile mantenere un profilo basso o un basso profilo (un atteggiamento prudente)
- molti programmi televisivi sono di basso profilo o di profilo basso (di scarsa qualità)

Basso profilo probabilmente è l'espressione più comune.

Dallo Zingarelli 2008, voce “profilo”

> - 6 (fig.) Sommaria descrizione delle caratteristiche di qlco. o di qlcu.: […]| ***Profilo basso, basso profilo***, linea di condotta che rifugge dall’ostentazione: mantenere un profilo basso; strategia del basso profilo | Di basso profilo, mediocre, di scarso valore: polemica di basso profilo
> - Come si vede, la locuzione “basso profilo” ha due significati ed è evidente che usare l’uno o l’altro fa una qualche differenza.

Comment: Ok, quindi sono corrette entrambe ed hanno lo stesso significato all'interno dello stesso contesto. Grazie